# TestNG - suite xml configuration file not showing verbose output

Tags: maven, testng

I am facing issue in setting the verbose output in TestNG suite config xml file.

here is my maven profile

```
<profile>
          <id>faster-test</id>
            <build>
              <pluginManagement>
                  <plugins>
                      <plugin>
                          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                          <configuration>
                                  <suiteXmlFiles>
                                      <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/faster.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                                  </suiteXmlFiles>
                          </configuration>

                      </plugin>
                  </plugins>
              </pluginManagement>
          </build>
      </profile>
```

and the config file faster.xml looks like below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="FasterSuite" verbose="10" >
    <test name ="standard">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="slow"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
       <classes>
           <class name="com.dao.SampleTest"/>
            <class name ="com.dao.Sample2Test"/>
               </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When i run the test using mvn -Pfaster-test it does not show any progress in terms of running the tests. Can someone please let me know if i am missing anything? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration in Maven:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <useFile>false</useFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `useFile` element should help.

Comment: :where do i put the suitexmlfile entry?

Comment: Same place. Nested within configuration.

Comment: thanks Vidya for your help but i am still not getting the progress output on the console--------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite

Tests run: 57, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 109.774 sec

Results :

Tests run: 57, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: Strange. It should be redundant with the Maven configuration, but try mvn -Pfaster-test test -Dsurefire.useFile=false